# What is Kendo UI autocomplete widget

Tags: user-interface, autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am a beginner to Kendo Ui controls. Can anyone tell me the purpose of using Kendo UI auto-complete widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autocomplete's purpose is to provide a list of choices on an input textbox, but not force the user into choosing one.  It will work similiar to a dropdownlist, but the user is free to put whatever value they want into it.

See demos at telerik.com  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/autocomplete/index.html